# Compile AngularJS pages and remove ng-* directives

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to compile AngularJS application to remove ng-* directives like (ng-click) and generate plain HTML like Angular 2+? If we inspect Angular 2 application with say chrome dev tools, it does not show event handlers like `onClick`. However AngularJS shows `ng-click`, `ng-for` etc.

Comment: What is the reason? just to make the dom cleaner? if so, this is the way AngularJS works :]

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
No.

**Long answer:**
I won't prvide one, as your question touches many (complex) topics that are already explained elsewhere and possibliy better than I could do, but I will provide some usefull links in my short explanation.

**Medium answer:**
What you asking for is not possible, because AngularJS uses a different approach for change detection and event bindings.

One of the cool things about AngularJS/Angular is it's ability to to detect changes and perform updates automtically. To make this possible, Angular(JS) has to notice if things change.

Taking your example with the click event, AngularJS uses event based directives to notice the click event, whereas Angular performs a [event binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#event-binding-event) using one-way bindng from the template view to the component. Angular has this possibility because it uses [Zones to get aware of changes](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html#who-notifies-angular). Therefore it doesn't need a directive as AngularJS did.

This explains why you don't see event handlers on the HTML element, because Angular directly sets up the event binding. You can verify that the event is handled by Zone.js if you check the *Event Listeners* tab in Chrome:
[image: Click event gets handeled by Zone.js]

Other usefull links to the topic:

- https://angular.io/guide/architecture-components#data-binding
- https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/22/understanding-zones.html